# Implementing a Generic Double Linked Class with refer to current obeject

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

For an assignment we were asked to implement a fully generic DoubleLinkedList class, and there was a part where I was unsure of that I need help with. I tried to search online, but I was unable to find an answer.

For the addToEnd and addToFront methods, they each have the return type as BasicDoubleLinkedList and should return a "reference to the current object"

When I try to retun a node, it doesn't allow me to because its not a BasicDoubleLinkedList object. I need to use "this" however, I am unsure how to actually go about doing it.

Here is my code so far

```
*my inner class node

public class Node <T>
{
 private T data;
 private Node<T> next;
 private Node<T> prev;

 public Node()
 {
 }

}



public class BasicDoubleLinkedList<T> {

private Node<T> head; // points to the head node
private Node<T> tail; // points to the last node
int size; 

 public BasicDoubleLinkedList<T> addToFront(T data)
 {
 Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>();
 newNode.data = data;   

 if(head == null)
 {
    head = newNode;
 }
 else{
    head.prev = newNode;
    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
 }
 return null;  <------------ I am getting a bit confused somewhere, as     I am not sure what to put for the return type that is BasicDoubleLinkedList<T>

}
}
```

Comment: Why not returning the actual instance like `return this;`?

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple, I just couldn't recall. Thanks again